# How to solve ambiguous outer join error while joining two sets of tables

Tags: sql, join, oracle11g

I have 2 sets of tables, each set contains a header and detail table. One of the set is the master set which contains the final list of records and the other set is the supplementary set. Each detail table has a quantity field. I need to join both sets of tables and summarize the quantity field of both sets of table but if there are less records in the supplementary set, I need to show a null with excluding the record itself.
Here is the query which displays the data only for the matching records, I need to display all records from the master set with null values in the quantity field of the supplementary set.

```
SELECT   LTOH.txn,
           LTOH.txnno,
           LTOI.itemcode,
           SUM (LTOI.qty) AS SumOfqty,
           SUM (BTI.qty) AS SumOfqty1
    FROM      (   BTH
               INNER JOIN
                  BTI
               ON BTH.hsysid = BTI.ltohsysid)
           INNER JOIN
              (   LTOH
               INNER JOIN
                  LTOI
               ON LTOH.hsysid = LTOI.ltohsysid)
           ON     (BTI.itemcode = LTOI.itemcode)
              AND (BTH.txnno = LTOH.txnno)
              AND (BTH.txn = LTOH.txn)
GROUP BY   LTOH.txn, LTOH.txnno, LTOI.itemcode
  HAVING   ( ( (LTOH.txn) = "ABC") AND ( (LTOH.txnno) = "1"));
```

Comment: Which table is the "master set"? Two code posts and I don't see any outer joins. Can you post the code that actually throws the error?

Comment: LTOH & LTOI is the master set which will have full records and BTH & BTI is the supplementary set which can have full records or less.

Comment: I'm having difficulty understanding and I need to go to bed soon but... does the posted query actually work? normally you need to alias those subtables i.e. you'd need something like `ON BTH.hsysid = BTI.ltohsysid) T1` which would alias that part as `T1` then this `ON BTH.hsysid = BTI.ltohsysid)` would become something like this: ON T1.hsysid = T2.ltohsysid)`

Comment: and by "less records" do you mean `COUNT(*)` or `SUM(QTY)`?

Comment: and is there a 0 or 1 to 1 relationship between the header tables? i.e. no double counting

Comment: Example: LTOH (header) & LTOI (detail) is linked with sysids , the detail table has 3 records, A with Qty 2, B with Qty 3, C with Qty 50. Now, the BTH (header) & BTI (detail) is also linked with sysids, the detail table has 2 records, A with Qty 2, C with Qty 50. It doesn't have record B with Qty 3. I need to display data such that LTOH & LTOI all records are displayed with sum(qty) and another field with sum(qty) from LTOH & LTOI tables, now in our example record B should show Qty 2 in the sum(qty) of LTOI but it will be null in the sum(qty) of BTI. Hope you understood.

Comment: header tables match 1 to 1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87275/discussion-between-user3625561-and-nick-mcdermaid).

Answer (score 0):

Change the order of the joins so that LTOI is first  as it relates to BTI already defined, and LTOH is last as it associates to LTOI and BTI.  Removed some unneeded ()'s as well.

Simply put, the joins must occur in sequence.  If relationships are defined as  A-->B-->C-->D then the joins must be defined in that order.  If you try to go A-->B-->D-->C; you get the error syntax you displayed as the engine doesn't know how to join D to A, B already defined.  SQL engines generally parse the FROM clause in order listed.  I say generally because, in Microsoft Access a user can denote ()'s to denote order for the engine to execute the joins.  I'm not sure if any enterprise RDBMS will do that, I usually define them in the order of the keys to make reading easier... sounds like something I need to try!  However, your ()'s were not adding value in your from clause to denote order.

```
SELECT LTOH.txn,
  LTOH.txnno,
  LTOI.itemcode,
  SUM (LTOI.qty) AS SumOfqty,
  SUM (BTI.qty)  AS SumOfqty1
FROM BTH
INNER JOIN bti
   ON BTH.hsysid = BTI.ltohsysid
RIGHT JOIN  ltoi
   ON bti.itemcode = ltoi.itemcode
RIGHT JOIN ltoh
   ON ltoh.hsysid   = ltoi.ltohsysid
  and bth.txnno   = ltoh.txnno
  and bth.txn     = ltoh.txn
GROUP BY ltoh.txn, ltoh.txnno, ltoi.itemcode
HAVING LTOH.txn = "ABC"
  and  LTOH.txnno    = "1";
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but it still displays only 2 records (matching the supplementary set). The master set has 3 records and supplementary set has 2 records. I need to display the 3 records.

Comment: Probably too late but I still think this can be achieved via simple joins with out the inline views using outer join syntax

Answer (score 0):

I got the desired results by using the below method:

```
 SELECT   LTOHGROUP.txn,
           LTOHGROUP.txnno,
           LTOHGROUP.itemcode,
           SUM (LTOHGROUP.qty) AS SumOfqty,
           SUM (BTHGROUP.qty) AS SumOfqty1
    FROM      (SELECT   LTOH.*, LTOI.*
                 FROM      LTOH
                        INNER JOIN
                           LTOI
                        ON LTOH.hsysid = LTOI.ltohsysid) LTOHGROUP
           LEFT JOIN
              (SELECT   BTH.*, BTI.*
                 FROM      BTH
                        INNER JOIN
                           BTI
                        ON BTH.hsysid = BTI.ltohsysid) BTHGROUP
           ON     (LTOHGROUP.itemcode = BTHGROUP.itemcode)
              AND (LTOHGROUP.txnno = BTHGROUP.txnno)
              AND (LTOHGROUP.txn = BTHGROUP.txn)
GROUP BY   LTOHGROUP.txn, LTOHGROUP.txnno, LTOHGROUP.itemcode
  HAVING   ( ( (LTOHGROUP.txn) = 'ABC') AND ( (LTOHGROUP.txnno) = '1'));
```